# Spring Integration: Reading from Kafka Queue

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-kafka

In a Spring Boot application, I want to use Spring Integration to read from a Kafka queue. The following is configured:

```
@Bean
public KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String>
adapter(KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container) {
    KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter =
            new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(container);
    kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(receiver());
    return kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
}

@Bean
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container() throws Exception {
    ContainerProperties properties = new ContainerProperties(this.topic);
    return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory(), properties);
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = ... // set properties
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public DirectChannel receiver() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Autowired
private Resolver resolver;

@Bean
public EventDrivenConsumer getEventDrivenConsumer() {
    return new EventDrivenConsumer(receiver(), resolver);
}
```

The `Resolver` bean implements `MessageHandler`.

Messages are received on the queue, but are not processed by the resolver bean.

The Spring Boot application is annotated as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
```

So there should be no auto configuration of Kafka beans.

The following is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:188) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:72) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:47) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:792) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:736) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2100(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:246) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1025) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_20]
```

Debugging, it is apparent that in `RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter` (top of the stacktrace), `this.methodHandler` is null.

What is the correct way in Spring Integration to connect the channel to the bean which should process the messages?

Comment: Looks like there is something else in your application not shown in this config. According your stack trace there is no any interaction with the `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. That one injects an `IntegrationRecordMessageListener` listener instead of mentioned above `RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter`. Maybe you can share this Spring Boot project with us somewhere on the GitHub ?

Comment: Artem, thanks. Have updated the question to point out that I am using @SpringBootApplication(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class) to explicitly exclude auto configuration of Kafka.

Comment: Thanks. That still doesn't help sorry. Maybe there is something else in the logs around that `NPE` stack trace? You also can turn on DEBUG logging level for the `org.springframework.kafka` to trace what and how is called. And maybe you'll figure out yourself who and how calls some listener container without a `handlerMethod`. May be you have `@EnableKafka` and anything else?

Comment: Artem, thanks. There is no @EnableKafka.
With debug I see:  s.i.k.i.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter : started adapter, 
soon after 
o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[].
I understand that KafkaMessageListenerContainer should not be getting instantiated, is that correct?

Comment: No, it has to be because it is a bean `container()` and it is required by the `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

This was the resolution:

The parent declaration for the project is as follows:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

For the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-integration-kafka.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

was previously using, for `spring-integration-kafka.version`:

```
3.0.1.RELEASE
```

Changed this to:

```
2.1.0.RELEASE
```

And everything works.

Without an explicit version for `spring-integration-kafka`, however, the project would not build because of missing classes.

One of the advantages of Boot is that it handles the dependency versions. Perhaps there should be a `spring-boot-integration-kafka` dependency, which would have prevented this issue.